# How to get the time slot of Telerik's Scheduler from client side by the time or date of that time slot

Tags: jquery, asp.net, telerik, radscheduler

I'm using Telerik's RadScheduler Control with WebService Binding.

I've used RadScheduler with Server Side Binding which has an event called `OnTimeSlotCreated` which fires every time when a particular time slot creates so that I can access the time slot and get the control (`HtmlTableCell` Control) to modify it according to the requirement.

But now I'm binding it from client side through WebService which has no such `onClientTimeSlotCreated` event, also these time slots are not having any identity at client side to access.

Is there any one has encountered such kind of issue or can give some suggestions please go ahead.

I've wasted lot of time on that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately,

There is no easy solution to this and we are not supporting this scenario.

Veronica,
The Telerik Team